Conciliating Git histories after rewriting history to remove Jupyter Notebook outputs
I'm leading a project with some students, where we use Jupyter notebooks for explanations and test cases in a private GitHub repository. Initially, we committed all notebooks, including outputs, but this became impractical due to large file sizes. We implemented a git filter using nbstripout to automatically strip outputs from new commits, but old outputs still clutter the history.
I'm planning on using git-filter-repo to strip all Jupyter notebook outputs from history. However, my main concern is how to reconcile the rewritten history with students' local changes, without them losing work or facing complex merge conflicts.
What I have found so far seems to point out that it is not possible to do this without messing the history of everyone massively (for instance, this answer by @torek).

@torek is an ace.... I would take his word very seriously... I didn't read it in full, though.... When you need to do this kind of stuff, it's something that you should fully understand instead of applying a blind fix.... I will provide an answer

So... Let's assume, for simplicity's sake that you keep a single branch against which all work is merged.... And users create their own branches from it. Let's say that from your repo, that branch is called X. Create a new branch called X-old from it and push it into the remote repo.
So, you run git filter-repo and you get an X branch that is 1 to 1, commit per commit, an equivalent of X-old but it doesn't have the bad stuff. You force-push this new branch into the remote so that the remote X is now clean from the files you removed from history.... Now the real fun begins.
Each one of your students will be able to see the two branches when they run a git fetch and all they need to do is move the other branches that they hold privately currently on top of X-old to have their commits placed on top of X (the new X).
This is done like this:
git rebase origin/X-old some-branch --onto origin/X

Which is read something like this: "git, please, would you be so kind as to take the commits that make up the history of some-branch that are not in origin/X-old and place them on top of origin/X moving some-branch to the last commit of this work when you are done? Here's 20 if you do that for me."
And tadaaaaaaaaa they have one branch on top of the new X and they can continue working as usual. If they want to push some-branch into a remote and they had already pushed previous work on that  remote branch back when it was based on top of X-old, then they will need to force-push because history of some-branch has been rewritten and git does not allow, by default, to push onto a branch when that happens.
Corner cases:

they included output files in the commits they just rebased: use git rebase --interactive to remove them from those commits. There are a lot of answers on how to do that.
they modified files that were removed in your branch rewrite process so they get a tree conflict when rebasing: git rm those files as there is no need to track them.


Thank you for this answer, I will do this! What is great is that the corner cases also do not apply: there is already a pre-commit in place that prevents committing notebook outputs, and no file should be removed during rewrite.

So far it worked well. I did some modifications to your idea: it was easier to set-up a branch new-main and have the students to switch for this branch. My biggest problem was if they had local commits that were not pushed, so I had them run the code:
git checkout main && git pull && git rebase origin/main --onto origin/new-main && git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/new-main
Once all run this, I force-push main as new-main and have run some code to change back to main
